# What is the purpose of async_std::sync::Arc?

Tags: rust

I understand why structures that may block the current thread, like `Mutex` and `RwLock`, need to be reimplemented to rely on the futures/waker API, but why does it need to do so for `Arc`?

As far as I understand, no operations on the standard `Arc` are blocking, and in the latest version, `async_std::sync::Arc` is just a reexport of `std::sync::Arc`.

Is this future-proofing, in case a future implementation of `Arc` needs to rely on blocking?

Which one should I use in async code, and why?

Comment: If it were for future proofing, I imagine they would have made them wrappers around the `std` types. My guess (but it's just a guess) is that this is not future proofing but convenience: That way `async_std::sync` has everything `std::sync` has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is to ease the transition from `std` to `async_std` as much as possible.

The [description of the crates](https://github.com/async-rs/async-std/blob/86d3d74180f076ccc21321a8f8d628df2b7e9772/README.md) starts with:

> This crate provides an async version of [`std`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html).

And one of its descriptive feature is:

> **Intuitive**: Complete parity with the stdlib means you only need to learn APIs once.

As for the [blog post that introduced](https://async.rs/blog/announcing-async-std-1-0/) it, it clearly mentions that `async_std` is mean to be a drop-in replacement of `std`as much as possible:

> With `async-std​`, **all that’s needed is replace `std​` with `async_std​`**, add the prelude​, and sprinkle in a few `.await​s`

(emphasis is mine)

Given all that, it makes sense that the developers of `async_std` would chose to re-export all types from `std` that don't need to be adapted to `async`: Users don't need to worry about whether types are `async` or not and don't need to worry about what to `use`.

Comment: A rather strange idea, isn't it, that people should "transition" from the standard library of Rust to a third-party crate, rather than just using crate(s) for the additional features they need on top of what the standard library has to offer (such as async file/network I/O, an executor, etc)?

Comment: But the point is exactly to use a 3rd party crate only for the extra features and use `std` where possible. `async_std` only reexports `std` types commonly used with `async` programming for convenience, rather than making its own types.